# Is there a way in Java to see if one field exists, then all fields must be populated?

Tags: java

I have addresses that need to be validated. Currently, we take in Street Address, City, Zip. I want to make it so that if one of these is populated, then the other two must be populated as well (the other 2 cannot be blank).

It would look like this
if(!StringUtils.hasText(AddressLine)) {
???

Comment: Can you show output example ?

Comment: Would an address without any data be considered valid?

Answer (score 0):

Use String method .equals()

```
if (!AdressLine.equals(""){                                                              
        if(!city.equals("") & !Zip.equals("")){
         //Do something
      }
    
    }
```

If you can have a Null String, just add: if word != equals, then...

Answer (score 0):

Simple approach:

```
boolean allBlankOrNot(String... parts) {
  Boolean temp = null;

  for(String part : parts) {
    //on the first element set the expectation: either blank or not
    if( temp == null ) {
      temp = StringUtils.isBlank(part);
    //any other element needs to be the same, i.e. if you get a different state you'Re done and return false
    } else if( temp != StringUtils.isBlank(part)) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  //no early out, so all are the same
  return true;
}
```

Better yet, use a `Predicate`:

```
boolean allMatchOrDont(Predicate<String> predicate, String... parts) {
  //same as above but instead of StringUtils.isBlank(...) use predicate.test(...)
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
 boolean valid = allMatchOrDont(s -> StringUtils.isBlank(s), streetAddress, city, zip);
```